# How can I grant access to a single directory, but for all IPs using iptables?

Tags: networking, bash, apache2, iptables

I am using iptables to block all IP addresses other than those in my whitelist from accessing my webroot.

I am using a dynamic IP address, so is it possible to grant access to one specific directory for every IP?

Answer (score 0):

No is not possible to grant access to one specific directory for every IP using iptables.

iptables doesn't know anything except network packet level details, and it must not take too long to handle each packet.